# How do I make an if statement validation in processing?

Tags: java, arrays, validation, if-statement, processing

I have been trying to work this out hours now, but I can't seem to find the solution.The code is basically an appointment program, and when it runs it pops out a box and the 'secretary' inserts the name and time of the patient. However, if I put "Maria" at "1200" and "John" again at "1200", the system will immediatelly replace Maria with John. My code is as follows:

```
String[] names = new String[2400];  // from 0:00 until 24:00

void setup()
{
  String name = "";
  do
  {
    name = input("Name");
    if (name.equals("ABORT")) { 
      System.exit(0);
    }  // end the program
    int time = int(input("Time code (e.g. 840 or 1200)"));
    names[time] = name;
    showAllNames();
  }
  while (true);   // loop never ends

}

void showAllNames()     // shows all the times where there is a name
{
  for (int t = 0; t < 2400; t=t+1)
  {
    String name = names[t];
    if (name!=null)
    {
      println(t + "\t" + name);
    }
  }  
  println("================");
}

public String input(String prompt)
{ 
  return javax.swing.JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, prompt);
}
```

How can I add an if command that checks that the position is null before writing - and otherwise warn the user?

Comment: How about checking `if (names[time] == null)` before assigning to it?

Comment: How would I do that exactly? Because I also need a pop-up box which will require a yes/no question of whether the information should be changed or not. @Eran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the index is `null` before writing to it:

```
if(names[time] == null){
    //Add the name
} else {
    //If the name isn't null, perhaps go to the next index, or throw an exception
}
```

What you want to do if the name is `null` is entirely up to you.

I would like to add a few suggestions as well:

- Make your names variable an `ArrayList`, this way you can add any amount of names without changing the variable.
- Don't call your `showAllNames()` method from within your loop, rather call it after the loop has ended.
- Use normal indexes instead of a time index, this way you won't have to do null checks.